# How to use the PHP mail() function on Heroku

Tags: php, email, heroku

I've a simple template with a mail form that references a php script to send a email with the `mail()` function. I did some research and I now know heroku does not support this out of the box, so I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041733/how-to-make-a-simple-php-app-send-emails-from-heroku-cedar-stack) and a few others, but it is still not working. Do any of you know a work around or a known solution?

Comment: You need to configure it to use a SMTP server  so have you configured it ?

Comment: I did! I'm using SendGrid. Or at least I think i did. I set up the addon and used the script shown in the link I posted.